# Calcular una factura de venta

Tags: jquery, ajax

tengo este problema y ya me encuentro estancado, agradeceré su ayuda.

Lo que estoy haciendo es un ticket de venta con todos esos datos dinamicos que se deberían actualizar con jquery y cambiar de valor(para luego enviarlos por post con php a una base de datos).

Los `<div class="row items">` los agrego dinamicamente con otro jquery que interactua con otra base de datos.

Los botones de + y - Cantidad tampoco funcionan, estuve probando y no me funcionan.

No estoy cerrado a aprender otros metodos cualquier ayuda es bienvenida.

```js
$.each($('.items'),function(i,v){
        var cantidad = $(v).find('.cantidad').val();
        var punitario = $(v).find('.punitario').val();
        var total = cantidad * punitario;
        var impuesto = total*(18/100);
        var subtotal = total-subtotal;
        $(v).find('.total_prod').text(total);
        $('#subtotal').text(subtotal);
        $('#impuesto').text(impuesto);
        $('#total').text(total);
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="productos w-100">
  <div class="row" id="prods_0">
    <div class="col-sm-2 text-center"><b>CODIGO</b></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4"><b>NOMBRE</b></div>
    <div class="col-sm-2"><b>CANTIDAD</b></div>
    <div class="col-sm-2"><b>PRECIO UNIT.</b></div>
    <div class="col-sm-2" id="prods_0"><b>PRECIO TOTAL</b></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row items">
    <div class="col-sm-2 text-center">4000600000</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">Item 1</div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <div class="input-group-prepend"><span class="input-group-text">+</span></div><input class="form-control cantidad" value="1" type="text">
        <div class="input-group-append"><span class="input-group-text">-</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 punitario">30</div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 total_prod" id="1">0</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row items">
    <div class="col-sm-2 text-center">4000600001</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">Item 2</div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <div class="input-group-prepend"><span class="input-group-text">+</span></div><input class="form-control cantidad" value="1" type="text">
        <div class="input-group-append"><span class="input-group-text">-</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 punitario">30</div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 total_prod" id="2">0</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row justify-content-end">
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-6">
      <b>Subtotal</b><br>
      <b>IGV 18%</b><br>
      <b>Total</b>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-6">
      <div id="subtotal" class="text-center"></div>
      <div id="impuesto" class="text-center"></div>
      <div id="total" class="text-center"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Verifica que en tu código consultes el texto y no el valor de un div.
Además, el subtotal creo que lo estabas calculando mal. Ojalá y te sirva.

```
$.each($('.items'),function(i,v){

        var cantidad = $(v).find('.cantidad').val()*1;
        var punitario = $(v).find('.punitario').text()*1;
        var total = cantidad * punitario;

        var impuesto = total*(18/100);
        var subtotal = total-impuesto;
        $(v).find('.total_prod').text(total);
        $('#subtotal').text(subtotal);
        $('#impuesto').text(impuesto);
        $('#total').text(total);
      });
```